# undefined reference to `cv::error(int, std::string const&, char const*, char const*, int)'

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, opencv, unity-game-engine

I want to build an .so C++ library with link to OpenCV with Visual Studio.
(My goal is to make an apk that uses the .so file in Unity)

I made cross-platform dynamic shared library project in Visual Studio and set proper project settings.

[image]
In Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, I added a path to the openCV .so file downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.1.0/opencv-4.1.0-android-sdk.zip/download)

In Visual Studio I can build below code.

```
void OpenCVForAndroid::TestMethod()
{
    cv::Mat img(10, 10, CV_8UC1);
}
```

However below code makes errors.

```
void OpenCVForAndroid::TestMethod()
{
    void* ddd = malloc(sizeof(int));
    cv::Mat img(100, 100, CV_8UC4, ddd);
}
```

> 1>C:\Users\ddd\Downloads\opencv-4.1.0-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:548:
>   undefined reference to `cv::error(int, std::string const&, char
>   const*, char const*, int)`
>
> 1>C:\Users\ddd\Downloads\opencv-4.1.0-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:561:
>   undefined reference to `cv::error(int, std::string const&, char
>   const*, char const*, int)`

This is because the constructor
`Mat (int rows, int cols, int type, void *data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)`
contains `cv::error` and the linker failed to find it.

I thought `libopencv_java4.so` would have `cv::error`.. but maybe it doesn't.

What's wrong with my code or settings?
Where is `cv::error` defined?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: I had same error. Issue was incompatible versions of .h and .so files.

Comment: @sklott It's really weird. The header file path is set to : opencv-4.1.0-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include\opencv2. All related header and so files are from same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason why the issue happened in version 4.1.0.
However the issue was resolved after changing OpenCV version from 4.1.0 to **3.4.6**.